# Conways Game of Life how to interpret rules

Tags: javascript, canvas, conways-game-of-life

I am working on a side project, Conway's Game of life in canvas and Javascript.
Technically everything is going smoothly but I have a problem about one of the rules.

One rule states that "Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.".

Currently I keep track of all living and dead cells, so these are only cells that have been drawn onto the grid previously. But I am unsure if the rule stated above also applies on a cell that is not draw yet.

So when is a cell considered "dead" or is a cell that has not been alive previously also considered dead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, cells in Game of Life may only be 'alive' or 'dead'. If they have never been alive, they are dead.

Comment: In that case I am better of tracking every cell on the grid instead of only alive or dead ones. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Yes, there can be no cells that are neither alive or dead. In each round cells may 'die' or may be 'born' but it is a binary system, each cell is either 'on' or 'off', 1 or 0, 'alive' or 'dead'

Comment: Thanks, I think this means I have misunderstood the word 'cell'. The way I interpreted was that a cell (sort of like a biological cell) was something an item on the grid that was or is visible. But this means every item either filled or not is a cell. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> One rule states that "Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.".

By that terminology, yes, any cell that is not *alive* is *dead*. There are only two states for the cells, dead or alive.